# Applying ladder operators to spin states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

This must be a really easy thing to derive because on the internet the result tends to be written down with the comment that it was calculated 'by applying the lowering operator'. I tried to derive it and can't see how it works; I'd like to calculate the $|\frac{3}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ state in the $2\otimes 2\otimes 2$ representation.

As stated in all the resources I've looked at this is achieved by applying the lowering operator to $|\frac{3}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\rangle$. In this representation the state is given by $|\frac{3}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|\uparrow \uparrow  \downarrow + \uparrow \downarrow \uparrow + \downarrow \uparrow  \uparrow\rangle$. When I apply $J_-$ I get:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(|\downarrow \uparrow \downarrow \rangle + |\uparrow \downarrow \downarrow \rangle + |\downarrow \downarrow \uparrow \rangle + |\uparrow \downarrow \downarrow \rangle + |\downarrow \downarrow \uparrow \rangle + |\downarrow \uparrow \downarrow \rangle)$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(2|\downarrow \uparrow \downarrow \rangle + 2|\uparrow \downarrow \downarrow \rangle + 2|\downarrow \downarrow \uparrow \rangle)$$

Now I know that's wrong, and it's exactly double what it should be. And I also know it's probably easy because nobody explicitly writes it out. I'd hugely appreciate it if someone could point out where I've messed up or what do next. Thanks!

Comment: Got it, there's a 2 on the LHS.